# How to set an id to option in HTML.DropDownList

Tags: html-select, dropdown, html.dropdownlistfor

I have an HTML.DropDownList where I can set datavaluefield and datatextfield like the following,

```
<select>
<option value="Fruit">APPLE</option>
</select>
```

Even, I can able to set the ID to dropdown list using html attributes but Since I need to set the 'Id' to the option like following,

```
 <select>
 <option ID='1' value="Fruit">APPLE</option>
 </select>
```

Can anyone share the idea on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the id attribute to set the ID to the `option` tag and use `this.value` into the `onchange` callback with `select` element.

Below is the working example

```js
document.getElementById("select1").onchange = function() {
    if (this.value == 'Fruit') {
        var optionID=document.getElementById('1');
        alert(optionID.value);

    }
    if (this.value == 'Flower') {
        var optionID=document.getElementById('2');
        alert(optionID.value);

    }
}
```

```html
<select name="select01" id="select1" onchange="handleSelect()">
  <option value="Fruit" id="1">Apple</option>
  <option value="Flower" id="2">Rose</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the timely help... I tried some other alternative solution to achieve my business needs. It works fine now.

Comment: you are welcome..!! you are also able to post your own answer to same question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, It will alert your selected value

```html
<select onchange="alert(this.value)">
    <option id="1">APPLE</option>
    <option id="2">Orange</option>
</select>
```